# How to increase size of rectangle and circle in \node and vertical lines inside the rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

```
\documentclass[12pt,table]{article}
\begin{document}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning} 
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[thick,->,>=stealth]
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]

\path (4,2) node [cloud, draw,cloud puffs=9,cloud puff arc=90, aspect=1.7, inner ysep=.3em](F1){}
(5,2) node[circle,draw,circle = 1cm](F2){}
(5,2.3) node[align = center]{}
(6,2) node[rectangle,draw](F3){}
(6,1.75) node[align = center]{}
(7,2) node[circle,draw](F4){}
(7,2.25) node[align = center]{}
(8,2) node[cloud, draw,cloud puffs=9,cloud puff arc=90, aspect=1.7, inner ysep=.3em](F5){}
(3.5,1.5) node[circle,draw,circle = 1cm](F6){}
(3.5,1.75) node[align = center]{};
\draw (F1) -- (F2);
\draw[->](F2)--(F3);
\draw(F3) -- (F4);
\draw[->](F4)--(F5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, extend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can compile as it is- Apparently you have in document some information related to this picture without which is not possible to test your code.

Comment: i want just to increase the size of recangle and circle and also want to vertical line inside the rectangle

Comment: i make some edit

Comment: Please make this into something others can copy and test as is. The begin/end{document} part are placed all wrong, and there is no document class

Comment: i am sorry plz check it again

Comment: Please, clarify where should be vertical lines in rectangle and how many you like to be there?

Answer (score 1):

You can define minimum size of nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                shapes.multipart, shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 9mm and 7mm,
  start chain = F going right,
   arr/.style = {-Straight Barb},
  base/.style = {draw, semithick, 
                 minimum size=3em}, % <--- define size of nodes
     C/.style = {base, circle},
  MPNh/.style = {base, % Multi Part Node horizontal
                 rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4,
                 rectangle split horizontal}, 
 oblak/.style = {base, minimum width=4em,
                 cloud, cloud puffs=9, cloud puff arc=150, aspect=2},
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain, join=by arr}]
\node [oblak]   {};
\node [C]       {};
\node [base]    {};
\node [C]       {};
\node [oblak]   {};
    \end{scope}
\node [C, above=of F-3] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

- In above MWE I took a liberty and draw you nodes in chain using the `tikz` library `chains` and also its macro `join`.
- Since your preamble is not known, I use `standalone`. You can replace it with ehatever, however, in this case you need load `tikz` package and delete `margin` option.

[image]

**Edit:**
Added vertical lines in rectangle nodes, i.e. rectangle is replaced by `multipart` node.

Comment: i also want vertical lines inside the rectange

Comment: @MubashirSheheryar, where? How many? Please clarify this in question by some sketch.

Comment: plz look to the above picture

Comment: @MubashirSheheryar, see edited answer.

Comment: @MubashirSheheryar, any news?

Comment: thanks bro very helpful

Comment: @MubashirSheheryar, policy of site is that if answer solve your problem (on the best way), you can accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of the answer). By this you awarded people who help you. BTW. as I have seen that so far you have not accept any from answers which you receives on your questions ...